# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console not working in Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.1

Im trying to log to the console, but when I do this:

```
//setup our DI
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
         .AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory()
         .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug))
         .BuildServiceProvider();

var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
        .CreateLogger<Program>();

var enabled = logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug); // This is true
logger.LogDebug("Starting application"); // does not show up in console
```

Nothing shows up in my console!  What am I missing?!?

Answer (score 0):

Following a [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/samples/SampleApp/Program.cs)

Try the following

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>()
        .AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>))            
        .BuildServiceProvider();

var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
factory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

var enabled = logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug);
logger.LogDebug("Starting application");
```